# Eclipse CDT Juno - Toolchain issue

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have installed cygwin and all the needed compilers like gcc, mingw ,etc. But when i try to create a c++ project, i only get GNU toolchains; no cygwin toolchain. When i try to build the Helloworld program, i get the follwing errors.

```
Error 127 occured while runnin autoreconf
make: *** No rule to make target 'all'
symbol 'std' could not be resolved
symbol 'cout' could not be resolved
```

Comment: I tried to run CDT on Ubuntu. I only got the first 2 errors there.

Comment: Pls help...issue still exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create new project, select Executable, then empty project.  That will allow you to select MinGW GCC
That worked for me.  All is good now.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the cout issue, make sure you add the correct path to the Path and Symbols include tab. Project->Properties->C/C++ Genearl->Paths and Symbols.  THe first time i ran eclipse, the AutoDiscovery got messed up, so i deleted and started over.

As for the make issue: I think I was able to find out what is happening. see this link: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/tree/155856 After i disabled Project->Build Automatically, restarted eclipse, the error still was showing for make, however the binaries are built fine. I deleted the errors from the view and they do not re-appear on build. This appears to be a bug, but I am not sure what the expected behavior is supposed to be

Answer (score 0):

You have selected incorrect toolchain when creating project, so eclipse can't find some source files and tools to compile your project. Try to create new project and select correct tollchain (you can select the one you need when you uncheck "Show only supported toolchains" in new project options)

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by unziping "org.eclipse.cdt.core.win32.x86_5.3.0.201406111759.jar" into "plugins" folder, then delete this jar, restart eclipse, the red and yellow errors disappear at all, only some specifical library missing still.

Good luck!

PS: Mine is eclipse LUNA + WIN7 (32bit) + CDT(newest)